# Computer algebra systems in logic and set theory

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, computer-algebra-systems

I am a big proponent of computer algebra systems (in particular Sage) and I know that I use sage a lot in my day to day research. When I'm learning a new branch of math, I like to see what packages are available for working with that branch of math, and I was surprised by how little set theory is available. Sure there are packages for working with sets, but nothing more advanced than unions, intersections, etc.

Obviously there are certain things in set theory that it would be unreasonable to ask a computer to do (show each partial function in a definition by recursion, if you want a function on some infinite ordinal at the end) but there are things that I think would be extremely helpful to those learning the field, if not to researchers. We as mathematicians are able to work in a finite metatheory, so there's no immediate reason why computers could not also reason about infinite cardinals, say, in the same way.

Why, then, are there no packages (or, at least, very few packages) for working with forcing posets, large cardinals, or even working with basic model theory? As a second, related question, are there small computable examples to work with? How do you test if your theorem is actually true? I trust my proofs, but it always feels nice when you actually compute something and you get the expected answer. Sage is such an integral part of "checking my work" that I'm not sure how I would go about doing research in a field without it.

Sorry if this is a naïve question, and thanks in advance for any answers ^_^

Comment: Why are there only a few mathematicians that truly grasp forcing?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila - I always assumed it was because set theory was going out of vogue right now. There are complicated modes of argument in every branch of mathematics, I'm sure forcing is difficult to understand, but that's hardly unique to set theory. Perhaps you could explain your comment slightly more?

Comment: There are not many people who understand set theory and forcing, and even less that are willing to write CAS packages. As for the vogueness of it, the British government just decided to sponsor a huge project on the axiom of choice and large cardinals... I don't know how right it is to say that we're going out of fashion.

Comment: The nature of the questions involved seems pretty different - you ask about computable examples, but I'm not really sure what there is to compute per se in most of set theory. Can you give an example of a theorem in set theory for which you'd like something like Sage to be able to provide some supporting evidence, and what that evidence would consist of?

Comment: @NoahSchweber - at the most basic level, it would be nice to send a well founded relation to its mostowski collapse, for instance. For a more complicated (and realistic) example, you could give a description of a model, and ask if CH holds, for instance.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor The issue with these is that the objects in question tend to be highly noncomputable. E.g. what does it mean to "give a description of a model"? (With the Mostowski collapse there are at least small examples we can whip up, but they're not indicative of how we actually want to use the collapse most of the time - which is on highly noncomputable relations.)

Comment: Actually, that parenthetical note about the Mostowski collapse in my prior comment is worth elaborating on. It would be totally doable to whip up a gadget for computing Mostowski collapses of individual hereditarily finite sets, and this would be great for students learning the concept. But once understood, the gadget would be pointless: when we're actually using Mostowski collapses in research the relevant objects are far too complicated to be concretely described in any good sense (does e.g. "$Hull(L_{\omega_1^L})$" really count as a concreete description?). The toy examples are *too* toy-y.

Comment: This is especially problematic as far as **trust** goes. When we verify a prediction of a theorem via a calculation, part of what's going on is that that calculation is somehow more "immediate" than the proof of the theorem in quesiton. But once the objects we're dealing with are sufficiently complicated, this goes out the window: we too quickly find ourselves in situations where the only way to prove things about specific examples is to prove the general results we're trying to convince ourselves of in the first place!